# How can you pull a last name from Person field in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column

I have built a directory list and would like to create a view ordered by last name.  The problem is using the Person field does not actually contain a string for my to base another field upon.  Is there a way to pull just the person's last name with a calculated field so I can order the people by last name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change your Person field to "Show field: Last Name" or create a new person field with "Show field: Last Name" and set it to equal your existing person field using a workflow.

Comment: Doh!  How did I miss that?  Talk about over complicating things.  Thank you Erin.